# Sequelize: Filter by association without including associated data

Tags: sequelize.js

All of the examples I have seen, including the documentation suggest that filtering by association should use the following syntax

```
[contrived exampled]
User.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Task,
            as: 'tasks',
            where: {
                status: 'complete'
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

But this style will include *completed* tasks. What if you want to filter by association without including the associated records? I'm not talking about ex post facto using `toJSON`. but at query level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) If you want to see Users having at least one task, you can remove the (optional) WHERE clause.
b) You can suppress the Task attributes, if you don't need them (shown below).

```
   User.findAndCountAll({
       include: [
          {
          model: models.Task,
          required : true,      // INNER JOIN....
          attributes: []        // no task fields shown in result...
          }
       ]
   );
```

Comment: That is one hell of a hack. Thank you so much for sharing.